# OpenGL: MultiTexture misbehaving on ios

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

I'm having a problem sending more than one texture to a fragment shader. Attached is a barebones test script. I'm using the GLProgram script to do the shader loading (http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com.au/2010/11/opengl-es-20-for-ios-chapter-4.html).

You will see in the Fragment Shader that I'm simply combining the two textures using mix, but it seems that I get the same texture for both texture1 and texture2.

```
// Extends GLKViewController

#import "ViewControllerImage.h"
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
#import "GLProgram.h"

typedef struct {
    float Position[2];
    float UV[2];
} VertexStruct;

const VertexStruct TestData[] = {
    {{-1.0, 1.0},{0.0, 0.0}},
    {{-1.0, -1.0},{0.0, 1.0}},
    {{1.0, -1.0},{1.0, 1.0}}
};

const GLuint TestIndices[] = {
    0,1,2
};

@implementation ViewControllerImage{
    GLProgram *glProgram;
    EAGLContext *context;
    GLuint uvBuffer;
    GLuint indexBuffer;
    GLuint positionBuffer;
    GLint positionID;
    GLuint uvID;
    GLint textureID1;
    GLint textureID2;
    int indiciesCount;
    int vertexCount;
    GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo1;
    GLKTextureInfo *textureInfo2;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupContext];
    [self setupShaderProgram];
    [self setupGL];
}

- (void) setupContext{
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    GLKView *glkView = (GLKView *)self.view;
    glkView.context = context;
}

-(void) setupShaderProgram{
    glProgram = [[GLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderFilename:@"TestVertex" fragmentShaderFilename:@"TestFragment"];
    //reguster Shader attributes
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"position"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"uvPosition"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"texture1"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"texture2"];

    // Link Program and output log if fails
    if (![glProgram link]){
        NSLog(@"Failed to link");
        glProgram = nil;
        return;
    }
    [glProgram use];

    //retireve attribute indicies
    positionID    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"position"];
    uvID          = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"uvPosition"];
    textureID1    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"texture1"];
    textureID2    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"texture2"];
}

-(void) setupGL{
    vertexCount =   sizeof(TestData)/sizeof(TestData[0]);
    indiciesCount = sizeof(TestIndices)/sizeof(TestIndices[0]);

    glGenBuffers(1, &positionBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexStruct)*vertexCount, &TestData[0].Position, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &uvBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(VertexStruct)*vertexCount, &TestData[0].UV, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(TestIndices), &TestIndices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    //Bind indicies
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

    //Bind position and UV buffers
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexStruct), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(uvID, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(VertexStruct), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvID);

    //Load textures
NSError *error;
    textureInfo1 = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] CGImage] options:nil error:&error];
    if(error.description) NSLog(@"Texture 1 error: %@", error.description);
    textureInfo2 = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] CGImage] options:nil error:&error];
    if(error.description) NSLog(@"Texture 2 error: %@", error.description);

    //Bind Textures
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(textureInfo1.target, textureInfo1.name);
    glUniform1i( textureID1, 0);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(textureInfo2.target, textureInfo2.name);
    glUniform1i( textureID2, 1);
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indiciesCount, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

@end
```

VertexShader:

```
precision mediump float;
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 uvPosition;
varying vec2 uv;

void main(void){
    uv = uvPosition;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

FragmentShader

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
varying vec2 uv;

void main(void){
    gl_FragColor = mix(texture2D(texture1, uv),texture2D(texture2, uv),0.5);
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this problem I'm having. I'm sure it must be simple. I've also checked GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS which returns 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh Snap! I figured it out. I was accessing the attribute and uniform locations incorrectly. Attributes use *glBindAttribLocation* and uniforms use *glGetUniformLocation* I'm using the GLProgram class which use convenience methods *addAttribute / attributeIndex* and *uniformIndex*

This is the offending code:

```
-(void) setupShaderProgram{
    glProgram = [[GLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderFilename:@"TestVertex" fragmentShaderFilename:@"TestFragment"];
    //reguster Shader attributes
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"position"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"uvPosition"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"texture1"]; //wrong - this is not an attribute
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"texture2"]; //wrong - this is not an attribute

    // Link Program and output log if fails
    if (![glProgram link]){
        NSLog(@"Failed to link");
        glProgram = nil;
        return;
    }
    [glProgram use];

    //retireve attribute indicies
    positionID    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"position"];
    uvID          = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"uvPosition"];
    textureID1    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"texture1"]; //Wrong - this is a uniform
    textureID2    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"texture2"];//Wrong - this is a uniform
}
```

And this is what it should be:

```
-(void) setupShaderProgram{
    glProgram = [[GLProgram alloc] initWithVertexShaderFilename:@"EmptyVertex" fragmentShaderFilename:@"EmptyFragment"];
    //register Shader attributes
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"position"];
    [glProgram addAttribute:@"uvPosition"];

    // Link Program and output log if fails
    if (![glProgram link]){
        NSLog(@"Failed to link");
        glProgram = nil;
        return;
    }
    [glProgram use];

    //retrieve attribute indicies
    positionID    = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"position"];
    uvID          = [glProgram attributeIndex:@"uvPosition"];
    //retrieve uniform indicies
    textureID1    = [glProgram uniformIndex:@"texture1"];
    textureID2    = [glProgram uniformIndex:@"texture2"];

}
```

I'm such a noob.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I think I have solved it. I need to start the texture unit indexing at 1 not 0. Otherwise TEXTURE1 is the same texture as TEXTURE0 !!

Incorrect:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(textureInfo1.target, textureInfo1.name);
glUniform1i(textureID1, 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(textureInfo2.target, textureInfo2.name);
glUniform1i( textureID2, 1);
```

Correct:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(textureInfo1.target, textureInfo1.name);
glUniform1i(textureID1, 1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(textureInfo2.target, textureInfo2.name);
glUniform1i( textureID2, 2);
```

Weird.

Comment: That does not really make any sense, other than a difference in numbering convention between GLSL and GL nothing changes between those two pieces of code. You bind the same textures, to different locations, but the locations are changed in both GL and GLSL so the result should be no different. _Are you sure you're not changing the texture bound to `GL_TEXTURE0` somewhere else in your code?_

Comment: It doesn't make sense, but it works. This really is all the code there is. I wondered if I wasn't packing the buffers properly causing some kind of corruption. However when I implemented this in the main app it still didn't work. This OpenGL programming is so painful! A couple of things that I'm not sure about is if I need to _glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)_ or _glGenTextures(...)_ but no change.

Comment: Keep in mind that `glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is only for the fixed-function pipeline. If you are using fragment shaders, it does nothing meaningful. In OpenGL ES 2.0 it actually flags an error (`GL_INVALID_ENUM`) because there is no fixed-function pipeline; enabling that state is a relict from ES 1.x and desktop GL pre-3.0.

Comment: When stuff like this makes a difference, I suspect that you've made a dumb mistake somewhere in declaring or filling buffers.

Comment: e.g. you're using Jeff LaMarche's code. There is/was a major bug in his buffer setup/fill code for 4+ years (never fixed in the blog posts) where two int arguments were wrong way around. Easy mistake to make (never use literal int in GL code! Always use named vars and check against the spec!)

Comment: Stuff like that causes memory leaks / misreads / miswrites, because you've told GL lies about what's in memory. Also: never EVER use GLKTextureLoader - it's badly broken, and the Apple engineer in charge of it refuses to fix (sent me a scathing email in which he ranted about his own Apple colleagues. Weird. Whatever - don't trust that code!)

Comment: Unbelievable! Is this why Metal has been introduced